# how to return a dictionary key as a string value Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm a beginner programmer and I have a question. I need to return a key value as a string in a dictionary.

```
choice = skills[(input('which attribute would you like to access: '))]
print('Testing, choice was in word')
user = None
while user != 0:
    print('\nyour current', choice[0] ,' skill is:', choice,)
    print('you also have', XP,'XP points left to distribute')
    print('''\nWould you like to Add or take away points
0. Go back
1. Add
2. Take away''')
```

Right where `choice[0]` I want the program to return the key value to the dictionary. and then after it says `'skill is: '`, choice,) is where it returns the value of that key.

I want to be able to just display the key as a string value for easy access in the program.

So for instance if the key is "X" and the value is "x" I want the program to spit out.

```
'your current X skill is x'
```

so far the end of the print function works fine.

Comment: `print('your current X skill is', skills['X'])`?

Comment: @Austin: i don't think, that your program works.

Comment: @Lutz Horn: Your correction is right, but it's not the original. May be the original code had false indent.

Comment: the code works fine, its just an iteration in the string I want to get. "skills" is the dictionary value that I assigned the list of keys/values.

Comment: this is just a slice from the program I'm working on. in my attempt to make the code cleaner to read, it'd be a big help to be able to get the code to read the key (X) and print out just the (X) and not the little (x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a dictionary as: `d = {'X':'x'}`

You can retrieve a value from dictionary as `d['X']`

The function `keys()` will return a list of keys in dictionary and `values()` will return list of values in dictionary. And if you don't know the keys and want to retrieve any item, you can use index `i` in list returned by `keys()`. Try this:

```
d = {'X':'x'}
print('\nyour current', d.keys()[0] ,' skill is:', d[d.keys()[0]])
```

The expected solution of your program can be:

```
choice = input('which attribute would you like to access: ')
print('\nyour current', skills[choice] ,' skill is:', choice,)
```

Comment: this worked for the most part. except the fact that skills[choice] returns the value and not the key, so it was backwards but switching it around made the program work as I needed. so thanks a lot! question answered!!